# Unable to `make` on CygWin

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to do a configure-make-make install using Cygwin on my Windows 7 32 bit machine. I have checked, and I have the `make` package installed (version 4.1-1).

I am able to configure using `./configure --prefix=/home/user/myfolder`. Next when I run the `make` command, I get the following: `-bash: make: command not found`. I am unable to figure out if this is due to the `./configure` not executing properly, or it has something to do with my `make` package. How do I find out which it is? Does `./configure` create an output file at the location `prefix=/home/user/myfolder`? If so, what is the extension of this file (.in? .am?)? Is there a way to manually point the `make` command to a file?

Comment: The error message means bash couldn't find a command named `make` command anywhere in your PATH. This generally means either `make` isn't installed correctly or your PATH is set incorrectly. It has nothing to do with with what `configure` did or didn't do.

Comment: What folder make is installed into? Is that folder in the `$PATH` variable list? (answer should be 'no')

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
How do I find out where my `make` package is installed?

Comment: You can use Cygwin's setup.exe for that.

Comment: `cygcheck -c` will show and check all packages installed.  `$ cygcheck -l make |grep bin` will show you that make should be in the usual `/usr/bin` so or it is not installed or you are messing your PATH setting.

Comment: I checked where my `make` is installed as mentioned by @matzeri , and it turns out it's installed in `/usr/bin`, which is also in my `$PATH` variable list. @jdartheny said that this is not where it should be installed. Now I'm confused if my `make` isn't installed in the correct location, or my `$PATH` isn't set correctly.

Comment: what is output of  `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: `echo $PATH` gives me a long list of directories, `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` included. Are you looking for a specific directory?

Comment: just `/usr/bin`. If `make -v` does not produce any output, run `cygcheck make` to verify that all dependencies are correctly installed.

Comment: @matzeri, thanks for your help. The issue is now resolved. I think my `make` was not correctly installed. I will update my comment once I find out what exactly I was missing. I must admit I have been hopping in and out of directories and I might have messed up something along the way.